# parsing virt-top in java

Tags: java, linux, cpu-usage

Is it possible to parse the result of the virt-top command using Java?

The first thing I did was to run virt-top command in java

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("virt-top -n 5");
```

But I don't see any output in the console. I'm using eclipse as my editor.
My goal is to get the CPU and Memory usage of the guests so I used virt-top and I'm planning to parse the result.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE:

I have used a code that I have found in the internet. I was able to get the output I needed using the command "virt-top --stream -n 2". But my problem now is parsing the result.

An example of 1 iteration would be this,

```
"virt-top time  04:25:54 Host localhost.localdomain x86_64 4/4CPU 2301MHz 7465MB 
   ID S RDRQ WRRQ RXBY TXBY %CPU %MEM   TIME    NAME
    1 R    0    0    0    0  0.0  0.0   0:06.42 CentOS"
```

I need to get the %CPU and %MEM only.

Answer (score 0):

use the inputstream of the created process to read the generated output.

```
pr.getInputStream()
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

Comment: I'll just put my relpy  in the edited form of my post since it's hard to understand it here in the comment section. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need to consume a `Process` object's output via `Process.getInputStream()`

Also, you should probably consume and display the stderr via `Process.getErrorStream()`.

Finally, if `virt-top` is curses-based, then you probably want to disable ctl characters. This is achieved with `top` command with `-b` switch.

Comment: I'll just put my relpy  in the edited form of my post since it's hard to understand it here in the comment section. Thanks!